# Gluing Magnetic Knife Rack/Holder/Strip to Inside of Backpacker-Style Wooden Food Locker so I can remove it later

Tags: kitchens, mounting, adhesive, temporary

I don't like having my cutlery loose on the floor of my food locker, so I bought a magnetic strip for my knife, fork, dessert spoon, teaspoon and chopping knife. Now I just need to affix it to the inside of the locker door so that it can hold the weight of all that cutlery, but will come off clean when I move out.

Could be glue or tape or anything else you can think of. I'm open to any suggestion as long as you are specific about what product I should google.

Limitations:

- I don't have a lot of money
- I live in New Zealand, so I can't necessarily get the stuff you can get in America.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do on this one, wood is poros and anything with enough bonding strength to stay adhered will sink into the porus and wreck the wood when it is pulled off.   Why don't you just ask whoever owns the locker if it's OK to leave it when you leave, if it's a good idea and not obtrusive I doubt they would object.

Comment: For a little weight as suggested, a very few things, silicone caulk or some type of double sided tape might work.  Will need to keep weight low.

Comment: For those of us in the States, a picture of the "food locker" would be helpful. This isn't a term we commonly use, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Is this a cabinet or a closet fixed to a wall or built into the house? "Backpacker-style" indicates that it's portable, but as one who _has_ backpacked, I've _never_ taken any sort of _wooden_ box for my food.

Answer (score 1):

Glue the knife holder to a larger piece of lucite or smooth wood. Larger is better because you can then use silicone to glue the assembly to the door of the food locker.